# Issue with Hartshorne definition of finite morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, modules, schemes

Hartshorne defines a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ to be an *finite morphism* if "there exists a covering of $Y$ by open affine subsets $V_i=\operatorname{Spec}(B_i)$, such that for each $i$, $f^{-1}(V_i)$ is affine, equal to $\operatorname{Spec}(A_i)$, where $A_i$ is a $B_i$-algebra which is a finitely generated $B_i$-module". In the example immediately following this definition, he talks about schemes of "finite type over $k$", which I assume just means that the morphism $X\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ is finite.

What disturbs me in this definition is the the part about being each $A_i$ being finitely generated $B_i$-*module*, rather than, say, a finitely generated $B_i$-algebra. For example, if $X=\operatorname{Spec}( k[x])=\mathbb{A}^1$, then $X$ is obviously an affine scheme over $k$ but the morphism $X\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ is not of finite type over $k$ since $k[x]$ is not a finitely generated $k$-vector space (though it finitely generated as a $k$-algebra). Thus, according to this definition, $\mathbb{A}^1$ is not of finite type over $k$, which seems wrong to me. Am I misunderstanding something here, or is this a typo?

Comment: Ah, nevermind. I think I was confusing the definition of "finite morphism" with "morphism of finite type", where the latter is defined using finitely generated algebras. So, to say that $X$ is a scheme of finite type over $k$ then must mean that $X\rightarrow Spec(k)$ is a morphism of finite type.

Comment: Your comment is absolutely correct and you should maybe consider self-answering your own question if you're going to keep this up. Secondly, a minor formatting thing: \operatorname{Spec} produces better formatting of $\operatorname{Spec}$ and I have made this change in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already mentioned this in the comments, but for completeness I'll put it here as an answer too. I was confusing the definition of "finite morphism" with "morphism of finite type", where the latter is defined using finitely generated algebras. So, to say that $$ is a scheme of finite type over $$ then must mean that $X\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}(k)$ is a morphism of finite type.

Comment: +1. A friend told me something once that helped. Geometrically, when you hear "morphism of finite type" you should think "anything at all that I care about." When you hear "finite morphism" you should think "finite fibers." (Both of these metaphors are wrong but they capture the spirit of the definitions and how different they are..)